# MySQL group by with start and end times

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table called map_item_group in MySQL that looks like this example:

```
item_serial | group_code | start_date | end_date
===================================================
item1       | group1     | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01
item1       | group2     | 2016-02-01 | 2016-03-15
item2       | group1     | 2015-06-01 | 2016-06-30
item1       | group2     | 2016-05-18 | 2016-06-30
```

I want to create a MySQL view called group_info that looks like this:

```
group_code | start_date | end_date   | items_string   
=======================================================
group1     | 2015-01-01 | 2015-06-01 | item1    
group1     | 2015-06-01 | 2016-01-01 | item1,item2
group1     | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 | item2   
group2     | 2016-02-01 | 2016-03-15 | item1
group2     | 2016-05-18 | 2016-06-30 | item1
```

In other words, I want one row for each group showing the items in that group over each time span.

Simply grouping by group_code, start_date and end_date (i.e. `SELECT group_code, start_date, end_date, GROUP_CONCAT(item_serial) FROM map_item_group GROUP BY group_code, start_date, end_date`) does not give the desired output.

I can imagine ways to do this with subqueries, but subqueries aren't allowed in MySQL views. I can create other views in place of subqueries as a workaround, but I'd rather avoid adding a bunch of extra views to my schema. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: You are using not full GROUP BY - try add `end_date` field to your GROUP BY expression.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant to say that the full group by doesn't work (with the end_date included). I've edited above.

Comment: There isnt a clean way to do this. You need split your ranges using subqueries and variables. In Sql Server or Postgres you could use LEAD() function. MySql need to emulate those.

Comment: Date columns are DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: @Aleksey They're actually datetime, I just made them dates in the example for simplicity

Comment: Try extract date part for grouping explicitly: `GROUP BY group_code, date(start_date), date(end_date)` and `date(start_date), date(end_date)` in SELECT instead of raw columns.

Comment: Do you want the dirty solution?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes please

Comment: can item1 be on group1 more than once?

Comment: It can't be in a group more than once, but it can be in multiple groups.

Comment: What's so great about views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First I create a list of all dates `(start + end)` by `group_code` using `UNION` I called `T1` but should choose a different name
- Then use variables to asign a row_number to each date. Subquery `T1` and `T2`
- Then have to duplicate the code to join the result to itself and create ranges. Subquery `R`

  - You could simplify it making that a separated view.
- Now I have the ranges, join back to the original table to see if the item belong to that range.

**OUPUT**

[image]

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/YTLSC96416)**

```
SELECT R.`group_code`, R.`start_date`, R.`end_date`, GROUP_CONCAT(T.item_serial SEPARATOR ', ') items
FROM (
        SELECT T1.`group_code`, T1.range_date as start_date, T2.range_date as end_date
        FROM (    
                SELECT `group_code`, range_date, 
                        @rn := IF( @grpCode = `group_code`, @rn + 1 , IF(@grpCode := `group_code`, 1, 1)) as rn

                FROM (
                        SELECT `group_code`, `start_date` as range_date
                        FROM Table1
                        UNION
                        SELECT `group_code`, `end_date` as range_date
                        FROM Table1
                        ORDER BY 1, 2
                     ) as T1, 
                     (SELECT @rn := 0, @grpCode := '') r
            ) T1 
        JOIN (
                SELECT `group_code`, range_date, 
                        @rn := IF( @grpCode = `group_code`, @rn + 1 , IF(@grpCode := `group_code`, 1, 1)) as rn

                FROM (
                        SELECT `group_code`, `start_date` as range_date
                        FROM Table1
                        UNION
                        SELECT `group_code`, `end_date` as range_date
                        FROM Table1
                        ORDER BY 1, 2
                     ) as T1, 
                     (SELECT @rn := 0, @grpCode := '') r    
            ) T2
          ON T1.rn = T2.rn -1
         AND T1.group_code = T2.group_code
    ) R
JOIN Table1 T
  ON R.start_date < T.end_date
 AND R.end_date   > T.start_date
 AND R.group_code = T.group_code
GROUP BY R.`group_code`, R.`start_date`, R.`end_date`
ORDER BY 1,2, 4
```